# My custom terrain generation plugin instantiates to much prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, terrain

The problem is the following: Normally the script should generate 16 prefabs in a cube around the player, when I start up it works fine because it calls the generate on start function, but when I step on another chunk with the first person controller it generates those 16 chunks every second, it creates a lot of lag and is really glitchy and shouldn't generate that much prefabs, any help is greatly appreciarted. Thank you very much.

I don't think asking such a big question as this is allowed, but after consecutive days of trying to fix this problem, it still doesn't seem to be working. So here is what I got:

- A first person controller
- 2 scripts

  - One script named `infiniteTerrain` which is attached to the first person controller
    *Short description of script: This script generates prefabs arround the player in the shape of a 
                                 cube. It also saves these chunks to a `.txt` file so they can be
                                 loaded when needed to minimize the amount of lag.*
  - One script named `chunkRename` which is attached to every chunk that is generated
    *Short description of script: Renames the chunks so they can be easy accessed in another* script.

Here are the scripts:

**infiniteTerrain.js**

```
#pragma strict

var terrains : GameObject[];
var newworld = true;
var trees : GameObject[];
var vegetation : GameObject[];
var rivers : GameObject[];
var mountains : GameObject[];
var playerTerrainUnavailable = false;
var x = 50;
var z = 50;
var y = 100;
var cameraDirection : float;
var chunkWidth = 50;

var chunk1 = " ";
var chunk2 = " ";
var chunk3 = " ";   
var chunk4 = " ";
var chunk5 = " ";
var chunk6 = " ";
var chunk7 = " ";
var chunk8 = " ";
var chunk9 = " ";
var chunk10= " ";
var chunk11= " ";
var chunk12= " ";
var chunk13= " ";
var chunk14= " ";
var chunk15= " ";
var chunk16= " ";
var chunk17= " ";
var chunk18= " ";
var chunk19= " ";
var chunk20= " ";
var chunk21= " ";
var chunk22= " ";
var chunk23= " ";
var chunk24= " ";
var chunk25= " ";
var load1 = true;
var load2 = true;
var load3 = true;
var load4 = true;
var load5 = true;
var load6 = true;
var load7 = true;
var load8 = true;
var load9 = true;
var load10 = true;
var load11 = true;
var load12 = true;
var load13 = true;
var load14 = true;
var load15 = true;
var load16 = true;
var load17 = true;
var load18 = true;
var load19 = true;
var load20 = true;
var load21 = true;
var load22 = true;
var load23 = true;
var load24 = true;
var load25 = true;

var canGenerate = true;


function Start() {
    if(newworld) {
        generateOnStart();
        saveLoadedChunk();
        newworld = false;
    }else{
        loadSavedWorld();
    }
}

function Update() {

}

function callGenerate() {
    if(canGenerate) {
    var canGenerate = false;
    var gameObjects : GameObject[] = FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];
        for (var i = 0; i < gameObjects.length ; i++) {
            if(gameObjects[i].name.Substring(0,6) == "ACTIVE")
                if(gameObjects[i].tag != "Player") {
                var xco = gameObjects[i].transform.position.x;
                var yco = gameObjects[i].transform.position.y;
                var zco = gameObjects[i].transform.position.z;
                generateFromMiddleOfChunk(xco, yco, zco);
            }                   
        }
    }
}

function saveLoadedChunk() {
    var loadedChunks : GameObject[] = FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];
    var fileName = "C:/Reactor Games/chunks.txt";    

    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    var write = true;

    var sw : System.IO.StreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true);
    for (var i = 0; i < loadedChunks.length ; i++) {
        if(loadedChunks[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "Chunk" || loadedChunks[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "_TERR" || loadedChunks[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "ACTIV") {
            if(loadedChunks[i].tag != "Player") {
                var xco = loadedChunks[i].transform.position.x;
                var yco = loadedChunks[i].transform.position.y;
                var zco = loadedChunks[i].transform.position.z;
                var stringToWrite = "Chunk (" + xco + ", " + yco + ", " + zco + ")";

                write = true;
                for (var chunkName in lines) {
                    if(chunkName.Equals(stringToWrite)) {
                        write = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(write){sw.WriteLine(stringToWrite);}     
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}

function generateFromMiddleOfChunk(xco : int, yco : int, zco : int) {
    //V1
    chunk1 = "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk2 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco+chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk3 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk4 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk5 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco+chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk6 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk7 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk8 = "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk9 = "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk10= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk11= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk12= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk13= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk14= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk15= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk16= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk17= "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk18= "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk19= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk20= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk21= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk22= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk23= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk24= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk25= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";

    var chunksInScene : GameObject[] = FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];
    var myArray : boolean[] = new boolean[25];

    for (var i = 0; i < chunksInScene.length ; i++) {
        if(chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "Chunk" || chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "_TERR" || chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "ACTIV") {
                if(chunksInScene[i].tag != "Player") {

                if(myArray[0] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk1))
                {load1 = false; myArray[0] = false;continue;}

                if(myArray[1] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk2))
                {load2 = false; myArray[1] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[2] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk3))
                {load3 = false; myArray[2] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[3] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk4))
                {load4 = false; myArray[3] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[4] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk5))
                {load5 = false; myArray[4] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[5] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk6))
                {load6 = false; myArray[5] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[6] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk7))
                {load7 = false; myArray[6] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[7] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk8))
                {load8 = false; myArray[7] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[8] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk9))
                {load9 = false; myArray[8] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[9] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk10))
                {load10 = false; myArray[9] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[10] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk11))
                {load11 = false; myArray[10] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[11] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk12))
                {load12 = false; myArray[11] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[12] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk13))
                {load13 = false; myArray[12] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[13] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk14))
                {load14 = false; myArray[13] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[14] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk15))
                {load15 = false; myArray[14] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[15] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk16))
                {load16 = false; myArray[15] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[16] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk17))
                {load17 = false; myArray[16] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[17] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk18))
                {load18 = false; myArray[17] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[18] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk19))
                {load19 = false; myArray[18] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[19] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk20))
                {load20 = false; myArray[19] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[20] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk21))
                {load21 = false; myArray[20] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[21] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk22))
                {load22 = false; myArray[21] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[22] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk23))
                {load23 = false; myArray[22] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[23] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk24))
                {load24 = false; myArray[23] = false; continue;}

                if(myArray[24] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk25))
                {load25 = false; myArray[24] = false; continue;}
            }
        }
    }

    //V1
    if(load1){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    //V2
    if(load2){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load3){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load4){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load5){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load6){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load7){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load8){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load9){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    //V3 
    if(load10){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load11){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load12){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load13){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load14){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load15){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load16){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load17){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load18){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load19){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load20){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load21){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load22){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load23){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load24){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load25){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}     
    yield WaitForSeconds(5);
    var canGenerate = true;
}


function generateOnStart() {
    //MOET EEN FUNCTION WORDEN DIE ALS DE SPELER EEN NIEUWE WERELD START, DAT ER AL EEN KLEIN TERREIN KOMT
    //V1
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    //V2
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(50, 0, 50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(50, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(50, 0, -50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-50, 0, 50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-50, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-50, 0, -50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(0, 0, 50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(0, 0, -50), Quaternion.identity);
    //V3 
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-100, 0, 100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-100, 0, 50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-100, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-100, 0, -50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-100, 0, -100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-50, 0, 100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(-50, 0, -100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(0, 0, 100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(0, 0, -100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(50, 0, 100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(50, 0, -100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(100, 0, 100), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(100, 0, 50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(100, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(100, 0, -50), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(100, 0, -100), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

**chunkRename.js**

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {
    this.name = "Chunk (" + this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y + ", " + this.transform.position.z + ")";


}

function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        this.name = "ACTIVE_Chunk (" + this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y + ", " + this.transform.position.z + ")";
    }   
}

function OnTriggerExit (col : Collider) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        this.name = "Chunk (" + this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y + ", " + this.transform.position.z + ")";
        gameObject.Find("First Person Controller").SendMessage("callGenerate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it against the rules? I'm sorry I'l edit it.

Comment: this code is a mess .. I was akin to ask if you heard about arrays, but then noticed you were using them in some places already. Seriously: use chunk[25] not 25 different variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, change your 25 lines of Instantiation to this:

```
for (int i = -2; i< 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -2; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], 
                          Vector3(j*50, 0, i*50), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

Secondly, you already have the gameobject in this call, so don't use GameObject.Find() //it's expensive
So assuming the object that is tagged "Player" has the FPS Controller, change:

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
    this.name = "Chunk (" + this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y + ", " + this.transform.position.z + ")";
    gameObject.Find("First Person Controller").SendMessage("callGenerate");
}
```

To:

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
    this.name = "Chunk (" + this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y + ", " + this.transform.position.z + ")";
    col.gameObject.SendMessage("callGenerate");
}
```

Finally, it looks like from your code that you want to have your generation based off of where the player currently is. Rather than do this in the OnTriggerExit, put it in the OnTriggerEnter() and then pass the trigger object to you function, saving you from needing to find the active object in the callGenerate method:

```
function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
    this.name = "ACTIVE_Chunk (" + this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y + ", " + this.transform.position.z + ")";
    col.gameObject.SendMessage("callGenerate", this.gameObject);
    }   
}

function callGenerate(go: GameObject) {
    if(canGenerate) {
        canGenerate = false; //you were redeclaring this variable here, 
        //which is mostly likely why you had more generation going on than desired
        generateFromMiddleOfChunk(go.transform.position);
    }
}
```

I can't find where it is that you are saving your chunks, but you will want to do this in a way that you only generate the new chunks that are needed.